# merge and convert swf

Tags: video, conversion

I'm having major issues combining/merging(lossless) swf video files into a single file then converting to something more useful(mp4).

I've tried using premiere but no audio as it doesn't import the audio. I have many of these files(hundreds) and need a simple way to merge them and convert. I don't really want to convert these files then merge then convert as they are already low quality and they don't need any more artifacts.

Comment: to me it sounds like a codec problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is: [SQUARED 5](http://www.squared5.com) MPEG STREAMCLIP it's a freeware converter with basic editing functions. The Batch function should help you.

Other possible software solution: [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm using WinFF to first convert to mpg then copy /b to combine and streamclip to fix the timebreaks. With WinFF I just have to drag and drop all the swf files and let it go(i.e., batch). Only one that seems to properly convert the swf files.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to accomplish is to extract the video from the SWF. A SWF is not a video file. It is an application or small program. There is an "FLV video" compiled into it. Try [SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/page/swf-decompiler/extract-flv.htm). It might be able to extract the FLV from the SWF.

Once you have the FLV (the actual video file), there are numerous video editors that can read and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

'Hundreds of files' sounds like you could go for automation, rather than a heavy GUI-based solution like a proper NLE. The command-line tool ffmpeg has an option you may find useful: the concat demuxer. To concatenate files with the same resolution, first create a file called `inputs.txt`, containing lines like:

```
file 'input1.swf'
file 'input2.swf'
file 'input3.swf'
```

One file per line. Then, using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt \
-c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast \
-c:a libfdk_aac -q:a 3 output.mp4
```

For more information on the encoding options, look [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).

For other concatenation options with ffmpeg, see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files).